# PHP -- Blank Page Due to Function Name

Tags: php

I have a PHP page that has a file included in it.  In that file, several functions are defined.  One of them is...

```
function median($arr){
    sort($arr);
    $count = count($arr); //total numbers in array
    $middleval = floor(($count-1)/2); // find the middle value, or the lowest middle value
    if($count % 2) { // odd number, middle is the median
        $median = $arr[$middleval];
    } else { // even number, calculate avg of 2 medians
        $low = $arr[$middleval];
        $high = $arr[$middleval+1];
        $median = (($low+$high)/2);
    }
    return $median;
}
```

With that function as-is, I get a blank page.  If I...

1.) Rename the function to anything else, the page works

2.) Delete the contents of the function, but leave it named as `median()`, I still get the blank page.

I have this same installation in a different area of my website and it works just fine.  I literally copy/pasted a dir and it's subdirs to another area of the website and now I have this problem on the copied version (original is still fine).

Any ideas on how I can troubleshoot what the problem is?

Comment: at the top of the file put `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` so you can see what the error is, remember to remove it for production.

Comment: sounds like you might be defining median twice, which is why it crashes. See php error logs.

Comment: A blank page when output is expected generally means a fatal error in PHP. _Always_ when developing code, turn up error reporting and display errors on screen. `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: white page of death, error reporting\display are off, turn them on `error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: "error_reporting(E_ALL);" for the win!  Thanks.  Incidentally, the other area of my website (that works) also should have choked on this because the median() function was already being declared there.  Yet, there was no error.  No idea how, but I've found out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, using `error_reporting(E_ALL);` showed that this function was already declared somewhere else.

+1 to the people who suggested using `error_reporting(E_ALL);` as a debugger.